# message attachment sent by office365 rest api is not shown in inbox

Tags: office365api

[image][image]I am using office 365 rest api and sending attachment, when I am sending attachment to any email address other than office 365 mail like(gmail.com, yahoo.com etc) then attachment seen in inbox, but in case of office 365 mail it showing only content.

Thanks,
Shankar

Comment: Can you attach an image comparing the two scenarios? I am not sure if I get what you exactly mean.

Comment: I have attached an image for getting attachment in gmail, please check

Comment: I have attached another image that showing content but not attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to send attachment to both office 365 and yahoo, gmail etc by using rest api of office 365.

Attachment array need to created as follows

```
     <?php
      $k=0;
         $attchmentArr=array();
        foreach($requestjson['name'] as $file){
                $attchmentArr[]=array(
                     "@odata.type"=> "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
                    "Name"=> $file,
                    "ContentBytes"=> $requestjson['content_bytes'][$k],
                );
          $k++;  
        }
?>
```

You need to create an array like following.

```
<?php
 $post_data=array(
             "Message"=>array(
                 "Subject"=>$requestjson['subject'],
                 "Body"=>array(
                     'ContentType'=>'HTML',
                     'Content'=> $requestjson['message'],
                 ),
                 "From"=>array(
                     "EmailAddress"=>array(
                         'Name'=>$fromName[0],
                         'Address'=>CARE_ACOCUNT
                     )
                 ),
                "ToRecipients"=>array(
                      array(
                          "EmailAddress"=>array(
                                        'Name'=>$toName[0],
                                        "Address"=>$requestjson['to_address']
                                    )
                            )
                  ),
                  "Attachments"=>$attchmentArr,
             ),
            "SaveToSentItems"=> "true"
         );
?>
```

then use curl to send mail

```
<?php
$url="https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/me/sendmail";
  $post_data = json_encode($post_data);
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, CARE_ACOCUNT . ':' . CARE_PASS);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $post_header);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);          

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            $response = json_decode($response, true);  

            $status_arr=array(200,201,202,204);           
            curl_close($ch);
            if(in_array($status,$status_arr)){
                return $response;
            } else {
                return 'error';
            }
```